# `docker buildx build` failing when referring repo with TLS certificate signed with private CA

Tags: docker, ssl, buildx

When building a Docker image based on an image in a private repo using a TLS certificate signed with a self-signed CA, everything works fine if that CA is already in the macOS Keychain or in the Windows Trusted Certificate Store – as long as you build using `docker build`.

However, when using `docker buildx build` the CA is not found and the build fails with a certificate error.

Consider this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/oraclelinux:8.6
```

With `docker build` it works fine:

```
% docker build .
...
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/oraclelinux:8.6
...
```

However, using `docker buildx build` it fails:

```
% docker buildx build --load .
...
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/oraclelinux:8.6
------
 > [internal] load metadata for dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/oraclelinux:8.6:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/oraclelinux:8.6
   2 |     
--------------------
error: failed to solve: dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/oraclelinux:8.6: ↩
  failed to do request: Head "https://dockerhub.my.private.mirror.org/v2/oraclelinux/manifests/8.6": ↩
  x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Does anyone know how to configure `docker buildx` to use the private CA certificate on macOS, Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 6):

My answer is based on this: https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/master/docs/guides/custom-registry-config.md

1. Create a buildkitd.toml and configure your private CA certificate:

```
[registry."your.dockerimagehost.example"]
  ca=["/home/downloads/mycacert.pem"]
```

2. create a docker builder

```
docker buildx create --use --config buildkitd.toml
```

3. then your build command should work

Answer (score 6):

This answer is for docker desktop environment under windows. I was having the same issue and the solution from @Lektro9 did not work out for me. However I was successful with [the answer stated here](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) The following content is based on this.

**Add Registry Certificate as CA in BuildX container**

BuildX for multiplatform builds runs in an own docker container and you will have to take extra steps to add trust to registries with self-signed certificates. The following steps use the tool [update-ca-certificates](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) to get it done.

1. Access the buildx container by opening a shell:

   ```
   docker exec -it buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0 /bin/sh
   ```
2. Go to the trusted certificates folder

   ```
   cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
   ```
3. Copy the registry’s certificate from the source location the container e.g. by scp:

   ```
   scp <username>@<sourceIP>:/path/to/certificate/of/registry.crt \
       ./<registrynameandport>.crt
   ```
4. Update the containers trusted CA list now by calling

   ```
   update-ca-certificates
   ```

   You can ignore the following warning, you might get

   > WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
5. Restart the builder container for the changes to take effect.

`docker build buildx` should work just fine now.

If unsure, you can verify if the process was successful by controlling the content of `/etc/ssl/certs` inside the buildx container. It should now contain an entry named `ca-cert-<registrynameandport>.pem` and it should also be listed in the `ca-certificates.crt` file.